# Recompiling with -fPIC

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install [Stage](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/index.php?src=stage), but i am currently stuck on this error, came up on [%49] :

```
 [ 49%] Linking CXX shared library libstage.so
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/stage.dir/blockgroup.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_ZTVN3Stg4PoseE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libstage/CMakeFiles/stage.dir/build.make:981: recipe for target 'libstage/libstage.so.3.2.2' failed
make[2]: *** [libstage/libstage.so.3.2.2] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:124: recipe for target 'libstage/CMakeFiles/stage.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [libstage/CMakeFiles/stage.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to look up how to fix it, but i couldn't find anything that is Linux-novice friendly, how can i fix this? how exactly do i recompile with -fPIC? i have no idea how i should go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason you chose version 3.2.2? I cloned the [git repository](https://github.com/rtv/Stage) (which appears to be at version 4.1.1) and it appears to have built without issues on my 16.04 box.

Comment: You are right, i tried installing 4.1.1 and it is working like a charm, i just didn't know it existed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add setting of cmake into `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -no-pie")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -no-pie")
```

Comment: Why? What is the result of this flags?